# Question on SyndicationItem - ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, rss, syndication

I am trying to understand how to use `SyndicationItem` to display feed which is RSS 2.0 or Atom compliant.

What property of `SyndicationItem` gives me the entire description of the post. It appears that there is a `Summary` property but per MSDN, it gives only the Summary. Also I have noticed that in my RSS feed reader, some RSS feeds show only a few lines of description and I have to click and go to the website for the full post. But in some feeds, I can see the full post within the Feed Reader.

Can someone explain how all this comes together?

PS: My web page lets user enter a RSS feed address and I need to validate if the feed exists. If it does, I need to grab the last x items and show the feed's title and full description

EDIT

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://feeds.encosia.com/Encosia");
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (var item in feed.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
            Console.WriteLine(item.PublishDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            Console.WriteLine(item.Summary.Text);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        reader.Close();
```

The first post's title, date and summary is:

I'm giving away 10 free months of TekPub this week
17/05/2010
If you follow me on Twitter, this stack of free TekPub trials may look familiar:
Each card is redeemable for a one-month membership at TekPub, which allows free,
 unrestricted access to all of the videos on the site. Of course, that also incl
udes access to my TekPub series, Mastering jQuery.
I've given many of them away [...]

###

Originally posted at [Encosia](http://encosia.com).  If you're rea
ding this elsewhere, come on over and see the original.

I’m giving away 10 free months of TekPub this week

If you go to the RSS feed, you will see that the post is longer than the output above

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want to get and what you actually get. If you can also post the source of the feed that would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.content.aspx) property?

> Gets and sets the content of the syndication item.

There are separate properties for [`Title`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.title(v=VS.100).aspx), [`Summary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.summary(v=VS.100).aspx) etc. There's not one property or method that return all the information for the item.

Comment: @bobsmith - I can't see anything else that would do what you want.

Comment: @bobsmith - what does `Content` return?